# wstringstream to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, stl

There is an open source code I am using and they created a new string class that they can have syntax's like :

```
   OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, String() << L"SOMETEXT" << UINT(123));
```

I was wondering if I can make a same thing conciseness with wstringstream or similar.

OpenEvent is Window API function that 3rd argument is LPCWSTR so you can call it like

```
  OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, L"some text");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a wstringstream variable named wss, calling "wss.str().c_str()" will do the trick.

This relies on the [str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/basic_stringstream/str/) member of the basic_stringstream class and the [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member of the basic_string class. Calling str on a basic_stringstream object obtains the string representation of that object and calling c_str on a basic_string object obtains the C-style string representation of that object.

Comment: So this way i still need a variable wss. Is there way to avoid doing that too? I know it might be silly. But that form is very concise, it is created temporary and I guess while exiting main function cleanup happens.

Comment: You might be able to do something like (wstring() << L"SOMETEXT" << UINT(123)).str().c_str().

Comment: Don't you mean `wstringstream()`?